# how to get the factors of a product

Tags: c++

I am trying to write a piece of code that will take the number let's say 24 and get all the factors for it so it would print the numbers 1 and 24, 8 and 3, etc. I tried doing this myself however I am fairly new to using c++ so it kind of confuses me a little. I apologize if this is really easy or simple to answer. could you please show me how this could be done?

```
int y = 0;
int x = 0;
int product = x * y;

while (true)
{
    product = x * y;
    x++;
    y++;
    if (product == 24)
    {
        cout << x << " " << y << endl;
    }
}
```

that is the code I tried doing it with but I realized that since x and y are increasing at the same time it will never reach 24 as a product.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than `y++`, try `y = 24 / x`. Just start `x` at `1`, not zero!

So:

```
x++;               // do this first, so x isn't zero
y = 24 / x;       // get closest y, rounding down
product = x * y; // see if it works
if (product == 24)
  ...
```

Comment: Do you know how I could get this to work for negative numbers as well as positive? If so that would be awesome.

Comment: Can you be more precise about what you want to happen? You mean you want to list `-8` and `-3` as factors of `24`? Or (`-8`,`3`) and (`3`,`-8`) as factors of `-24`?

Comment: of -24 i am going to make 24 a variable from input so if I typed in a negative number it would give me the factors of that negative number as well as positive numbers. So yeah it would be (-8, 3) and (3, -8).

Comment: So then test if the number is negative. If so, set a flag and change the sign of the number to positive. When you find pair of factors, test the flag. If it's set, output them twice, once with a minus sign in front of each number.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a quick code snippet :

```
for (int i = 1; i <= n; ++i) { 
    if (n % i == 0) {
        std::cout << i;
    }
}
```

Note that it is not optimized.

Answer (score 1):

You should start x and y on opposite directions. (i.e x=1 and y=24) and moving them closer to each other until you reach the median (i.e 12). 
e.g

1. x=1 y=24 --> product=24,
2. x=1, y=23 --> product=23<24 so x++
3. x=2, y=23 --> product=46>24 so y--
4. x=2, y=22 --> product ...

It is more algorithmic what you ask rather than c++.

Comment: It seems like a better explanation of this would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You will want to loop from 1 to that number; if the number you are testing, modulo your current loop index is 0, then it is a factor.

This is readily translated into code.  Here's a hint: % is the modulo operator.

If a specific step trips you up, feel free to ask here.  But try to translate the above first.